# Javascript filter array throwing errors and crashing

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript

I am writing a mobile app based on NativeScript, in Typescript/ JavaScript. This snippet of code is called after a Bluetooth scan has been completed. I need to find the correct service. My code works up until I try to select the service I want from the options. The `services.filter(function (obj) {` line seems to be causing the app to crash, but the error log doesn't make much sense to me...

```
console.log("Connect Variable");
var services: Array<string>;
var service: any;
services = []; //initialise array
bluetooth.connect(
    {
     UUID: _peripheral.UUID,
     // NOTE: we could just use the promise as this cb is only invoked once
        onConnected: function (peripheral) {
            console.log("------- Peripheral connected: " + JSON.stringify(peripheral));
            // Put all Services into an Array
            peripheral.services.forEach(function (value) {
                console.log("---- ###### adding service: " + value.UUID);
                services.push(value);
            });

            //search for the correct service
            service = peripheral.services.filter(function (obj) { // <- PROBLEM LINE ****************** Caudsing the app to crash out ...
                return obj.UUID == 'A000';
            });
        },
    }
);
```

Here is the console log:

```
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/Pages/Home/home.component.js:145:32: ---- ###### adding service: A000
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/Pages/Home/home.component.js:145:32: ---- ###### adding service: 180A
***** Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****
Native stack trace:
1   0xbea99 NativeScript::FFICallback<NativeScript::ObjCMethodCallback>::ffiClosureCallback(ffi_cif*, void*, void**, void*)
2   0x4ae381 ffi_closure_inner_SYSV
3   0x4b20b8 ffi_closure_SYSV
4   0x25e59d15 <redacted>
5   0x25e59e4b <redacted>
6   0x25e5f9f3 <redacted>
7   0x208d1823 <redacted>
8   0x208d180f <redacted>
9   0x208dfba9 <redacted>
10  0x20d25bdd <redacted>
11  0x20d240d7 <redacted>
12  0x20c732e9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
13  0x20c730d5 CFRunLoopRunInMode
14  0x22263ac9 GSEventRunModal
15  0x253380b9 UIApplicationMain
16  0x4b202c ffi_call_SYSV
17  0x4ae0c3 ffi_call
18  0x91a0b NativeScript::FFICall::call(JSC::ExecState*)
19  0x2e4931 JSC::LLInt::setUpCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Instruction*, JSC::CodeSpecializationKind, JSC::JSValue, JSC::LLIntCallLinkInfo*)
20  0x2e2579 llint_slow_path_call
21  0x2ea1ed llint_entry
22  0x2ea1f9 llint_entry
23  0x2ea1f9 llint_entry
24  0x2ea4c1 llint_entry
25  0x2ea1f9 llint_entry
26  0x2e5021 vmEntryToJavaScript
27  0x2a4cd9 JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*)
28  0x28d713 JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&)
29  0x38be87 JSC::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&)
30  0x9e943 NativeScript::GlobalObject::moduleLoaderEvaluate(JSC::JSGlobalObject*, JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::JSValue)
31  0x44c4f9 JSC::ModuleLoaderObject::evaluate(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::JSValue)
JavaScript stack trace:
1   onConnected@file:///app/Pages/Home/home.component.js:157:55
2   peripheralDidDiscoverCharacteristicsForServiceError@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-bluetooth/bluetooth.js:111:23
3   UIApplicationMain@[native code]
4   start@file:///app/tns_modules/application/application.js:233:26
5   @file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/application.js:65:26
6   ZoneAwarePromise@file:///app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:542:38
7   nativeScriptBootstrap@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/application.js:64:23
8   anonymous@file:///app/main.js:5:36
9   evaluate@[native code]
10  moduleEvaluation@[native code]
11  @[native code]
12  promiseReactionJob@[native code]
JavaScript error:
```

What have I done wrong?

## Update:

Following Vladimir's answer, I have this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < peripheral.service.count; i++) {
   if (peripheral.services.objectAtIndex(i).UUID == 'A000') {
      service = peripheral.services.objectAtIndex(i);
      console.log("selected service: ");
   }
}
```

However, I still get this output:

> JavaScript error:
>   file:///app/Pages/Home/home.component.js:98:56: JS ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'peripheral.service.count')

Comment: Is the syntax of object passed to `bluetooth.connect` correct? I dont see closing `})`.

Comment: @AdityaSingh I think so, It's just the excerpt I have put in. Alos, the fact that the code runs up until that point.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is NSArray not JavaScript array and that's why you cannot use `filter()`. Possible solution will be to loop the native `NSArray` and copy only needed objects or you can copy all objects and later use `filter`. Here is an example how to copy all objects:

```
var services = [];
for (let i = 0; i < peripheral.services.count; i++) {
   services.push(peripheral.services.objectAtIndex(i));
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question, please see the error your solution is throwing - I'd be really grateful if you could take a look

Comment: Can you verify if this object is NSArray? Simple console.log with typeof will do the work.

Comment: I get the same for `peripheral.services` and `_peripheral.service` and `_peripheral.services` ...